# How to stub Array instance method using RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, stub

I have an instance method in String class who call the Array instance method "shuffle". In order for me to test the method using RSpec, I want to stub it.

```
vowels = %w(a e i o u y)
vowels.shuffle
```

I tried:

```
Array.stub(:shuffle).and_return(%w(a e i o u y))
[].stub(:shuffle).and_return(%w(a e i o u y))
```

But none work :( I am missing something here ? Mocking maybe ? But what should I mock then...

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `any_instance`. For example:

```
describe "any_instance.stub" do
  it "returns the specified value on any instance of the class" do
    Array.any_instance.stub(:shuffle).and_return(%w(a e i o u y))

    o = Array.new
    o.shuffle.should eq(%w(a e i o u y))
  end
end
```

[Source](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class)